# Ошибка: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: java, android

Из класса BroadcastReceiver запускаю метод, который находится в главном классе приложения:

```
public void ShowDB(Context context){
    ArrayAVR = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAVR.clear();
    SQLiteDatabase mDataBase = DatabaseAvrHelper.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
    String readQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseAvrHelper.DATABASE_TABLE_AVR + " ORDER BY " + DatabaseAvrHelper.DATE_EI_COLUMN;
    Cursor cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery(readQuery, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper._ID));
        String Num_ei = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.NUM_EI_COLUMN));
        String Status_Ei = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.STATUS_EI_COLUMN));
        //String Error_Code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.ERROR_CODE_EI_COLUMN));
        //String Comment_Ei = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.COMMENT_EI_COLUMN));
        Long Date_Ei = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAvrHelper.DATE_EI_COLUMN));
        String dateString = null;
        if (Date_Ei != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM HH:mm");
            dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Date_Ei));
        }
        ArrayAVR.add(0, "№: " + Num_ei + " - " + Status_Ei + " - " + dateString);
    }
    mDataBase.close();
    ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayAVR);
    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    listview.setAdapter(ListAdapter);

}
```

При выполнении метода, Java ругается на строку:

```
ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayAVR);
```

мол рано выполняется код.

Как правильно объявить адаптер в моем случае? Нужно, что бы метод выполнялся обязательно при срабатывании BroadcastReceiver, если это вообще возможно, если нет, то какие есть варианты.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.hakeem.avr.SmsBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2616)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
        at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5035)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
        at com.hakeem.avr.Open_Close_AVR.ShowDB(Open_Close_AVR.java:155)
        at com.hakeem.avr.SmsBroadcastReceiver.UpdateDB(SmsBroadcastReceiver.java:69)
        at com.hakeem.avr.SmsBroadcastReceiver.SmsFromPdus(SmsBroadcastReceiver.java:43)
        at com.hakeem.avr.SmsBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SmsBroadcastReceiver.java:27)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2609)
```

В общем разобрался я с BroadcasrReceiver.
Если я регистрирую приемник внутри класса `MyActivity`, в методе `onResume()`, то все работает как надо, но и срабатывать он будет только если приложение запущено. Но мне нужно, что бы срабатывало всегда, поэтому так же инициализирую этот же приемник в манифесте приложения. Получается, что один и тот же код у меня дублируется, одна копия кода находится внутри класса `MyActivity` c вызовом метода `showFromDB`, вторая копия кода находится в классе `SmsBroadcastReceiver`, но уже без вызова метода `showFromDB`, т.к. при открытии приложения этот метод сработает при выполнении `onCreate()` класса `MyActivity`.

Теперь у меня вопрос: такое дублирование кода - это нормально?

Comment: потому что this у вас null. У вас метод вызывается до инициализации вашего активити.

Comment: + используйте свой кастомный  СursorAdapter вместо ArrayAdapter

Comment: То есть, если передать Context этого активити, то метод сработает? Или нужно еще обязательно CursorAdapter использовать? Мой_Активити.this не работает (

Comment: в  CursorAdapter нужно разбираться, а на перых порах подойдёт исправление ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayAVR);

Comment: Тот Context нулевой у меня ( Как из другого класса получить Context активити? :|

Comment: Если это, как вы сказали класс BroadcastReceiver, то у него вы должны были переопределить метод onReceive(Context context, Intent intent). контекст из метода и юзайте

Comment: Да, сработало, только теперь на следующую строчку ругается (

Comment: android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Все правильно. в onCreate() у вас разметка не легка, с которой вы пытаетесь выдернуть ваш listview

Comment: @АлександрХакимов Я правильно понимаю что вы из ```BroadcastReceiver'a```, который даже не является внутренним классом для основной ```activity``` пытаетесь выполнить код в ```activity```, которая к тому же еще и не запущена? Если это так, то я советую вам еще разок почитать про ```Activity```, ```BroadcastReceiver`` и все что с этим связанно.

Comment: Активити запущена. А про внутренний не внутренний, тяжело мне сказать. ( буду разбираться с этим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще хочется дать пару советов. В яве используется "горбатый стиль" написания кода. То есть названия классов с большой буквы, а переменные и методы с маленькой. Плюс создайте класс, который будет работать исключительно с базой, и читать удобней, и вызываться будет всегда из одного места. В результате у вас должно получиться нечто такого:

```
 public void showFromDB(Context context){
        arrayAVR = DBAdapter.getAVRfromDB(context);       
        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayAVR );
        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        listview.setAdapter(ListAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: Привел код к рекомендуемому виду, но так и ругается на ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2); ( И кстати метод getAVRfromDB статичный должен быть?

Comment: Я так понял нужно использовать BaseAdapter?